# Cannot delete User in GORM

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-orm

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to delete a Interviewee in the GORM :

```
Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK_APCC8LXK2XNUG8377FATVBN04: 
PUBLIC.USER_ROLE FOREIGN KEY(USER_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.USERS(ID) (40)"; 
SQL statement: delete from users where id=? and version=? [23503-176]
```

And this is my domain :

```
package com.cgi.recruitmenttest

import com.cgi.security.User

class Interviewee extends User{

String firstName
String lastName
String email
String telephone
String level
static hasMany = [results:Result,tests:TestInterviewe]

static constraints = {
    lastName()
    firstName()
    email(email: true)
    telephone(nullable: true)
    level inList: ['Debutant', 'Confirme', 'Expert']
}
```

}

I just try to create a interviewee without results and tests but when I delete, i get this error..

Can someone help ? Thanks

Comment: how are you deleting?

Comment: I use the default method delete with scaffolding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to delete a data from `USERS` table but in `USER_ROLE` table it contained a foreign key (named USER_ID) of `USERS` table. That's why you are unable to delete. Delete `USER_ROLE` table's data first according `USERS` table ID then you may able to delete.